# Calculate if two following 2D vectors have a left or right rotation

Tags: vectors, rotations, angle

I have 3 Points (x,y) that represent mouse movement (from Point 1 over Point 2 to Point 3).

The angle between the two lines (line between `p1` and `p2` & line between `p2` and `p3`) can be caluculated with

[image: Calculate angle between vectors]

where `a = [(p1.x - p2.x), (p1.y - p2.y)]` and `b = [(p3.x - p2.x), (p3.y - p2.y)]`

But the angle is just the inner angle and doesn't tell me **if the line rotates / moves left, straight or right**.

Here my problem in a example:

[image: vector movement / rotation]

I want to calculate that the movement from `p1` to `p3` over `p2` has a right rotation and the movement from `p1` to `p4` over `p2` has a left rotation.
Both have the same angle.

In other words: If you follow the vector `a` longer than point `p2` is `p3`/`p4` on the line, left of the line or right of the line.

How can i calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the vector product of two vectors $\vec x\times \vec y$. In $2D$ it writes as $\vec x\times \vec y = x_1y_2-x_2y_1$. If this quantity is positive, then the rotation is in positive direction (anticlockwise), if it is zero, then the vectors are colinear (or at least one of them is a zero vector), and if it is negative, then the rotation goes in negative direction (clockwise).

You might want to read the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) on vector product.